# Use scientific notation in p-value produced by gtsummary table

Tags: p-value, gtsummary

I am trying to display the p-value of a test produced in a gtsummary table in scientific format. So I want my p-value's to look like `2e-16` instead of `<0.001`. See table below.

Any suggestions how I can do this using the gtsummary package? I have put together a reproducible code below:

```
# download pacman package if not installed, otherwise load it
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages(pacman)

# loads relevant packages using the pacman package
pacman::p_load(
  tidyverse, # for pipes
  gtsummary) # for tables

# 2by2 table 
trial %>%
  tbl_cross(row = trt, 
            col = response) %>% 
  add_p()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can get the p-value you're looking for!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'

# 2by2 table 
tbl <-
  trial %>%
  tbl_cross(row = trt, 
            col = response) %>% 
  add_p() %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(p.value ~ function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, format(x, digits = 2, scientific = TRUE)))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The `add_p()` function has argument `pvalue_fun=` that *should* specify the function that formats/styles. But I see that the argument is being ignored (I'll fix this in the next version).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
trial %>%
  tbl_cross(row = trt, 
            col = response) %>% 
  add_p() %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = p.value,
    rows = p.value < 0.001,
    fmt_fun = scales::scientific
  )
```